# Can I put the data from one object to another if I don't need all of the properties?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of PhraseAndScore

```
public class PhraseAndScore
{
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Romaji { get; set; }
    public string Kana { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    public int OneHash { get; set; }
    public int TwoHash { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyA { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyB { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyC { get; set; }
    public int? JapaneseForBusyPeople { get; set; }
    public int? AJlpt { get; set; }
    public int? TJlpt { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int EnglishCorrect { get; set; }
    public int KanaCorrect { get; set; }
    public int RomajiCorrect { get; set; }
    public int KanjiCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to use this data to populate a list of Phrase:

```
public class Phrase
{
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Romaji { get; set; }
    public string Kana { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    public int OneHash { get; set; }
    public int TwoHash { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyA { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyB { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyC { get; set; }
    public int? JapaneseForBusyPeople { get; set; }
    public int? AJlpt { get; set; }
    public int? TJlpt { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

When I try this it gives me an error:

```
List<Phrase> all = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>(select + filter);
```

Is there a way I can take the PhraseAndScore data and fit the columns into Phrase or would I need to do a LINQ select and itemize every column?

I tried this also but it does not work:

```
     List<Phrase> xx = all.Select(pas => new Phrase()
            {
                PhraseId = pas.PhraseId,
                CategoryId = pas.CategoryId,
                English = pas.English,
                Romaji = pas.Romaji,
                Kana = pas.Kana,
                Kanji = pas.Kanji,
                Modified = pas.Modified,
                Favorite = pas.Favorite,
                WordType = pas.WordType,
                Hidden = pas.Hidden,
                OneHash = pas.OneHash,
                TwoHash = pas.TwoHash,
                FrequencyA = pas.FrequencyA,
                FrequencyB = pas.FrequencyB,
                FrequencyC = pas.FrequencyC,
                JapaneseForBusyPeople = pas.JapaneseForBusyPeople,
                AJlpt = pas.AJlpt,
                TJlpt = pas.TJlpt,
                Selected = pas.Selected
            });
```

Comment: What is `select + filter` doing?

Comment: You can use Automapper library which can do this for you.

Comment: You could use reflection to enumerate all properties and copy those that exist in in both classes. (Or simply inherit the one with more info from the one with less)

Comment: I tried what you mention with inherit but it still says it cannot convert: public class PhraseAndScore : Phrase
    {
        public int EnglishCorrect { get; set; }
        public int KanaCorrect { get; set; }
        public int RomajiCorrect { get; set; }
        public int KanjiCorrect { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You could provide a method `public static GetPhrase(PhraseAndScore pac){ return new Phrase{...} }` in `PhraseAndScore`. Then you only have to implement the property mapping once and your LIQN query looks like `db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>(PhraseAndScore.GetPhrase)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - can you give an example of this in an answer.  I actually only have to do this mapping one time anyway.  However all of the suggestions I have sense so far give me the same result.  Saying that I cannot convert from List<PhraseAndSource> to List<Phrase>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to complete the `select` statement and initialize new `Phrase` out `PhraseAndScore`.

```
List<Phrase> all = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>().Where(filter)
    .Select(pas => new Phrase 
        { 
            PhraseId = pas.PhraseId,
            CategoryId = pas.CategoryId
            .
            .
            .
        })
```

Another (more advanced) method would be to create an interface for your phrase and implement it by any object that is actually a phrase. Then, instead of a `List<Phrase>` you utilize a `List<IPhrase>`...

```
public interface IPhrase
{
    string PhraseId { get; set; }
    int CategoryId { get; set; }
    string English { get; set; }
    string Romaji { get; set; }
    string Kana { get; set; }
    string Kanji { get; set; }
    int Modified { get; set; }
    bool Favorite { get; set; }
    string WordType { get; set; }
    bool Hidden { get; set; }
    int OneHash { get; set; }
    int TwoHash { get; set; }
    int? FrequencyA { get; set; }
    int? FrequencyB { get; set; }
    int? FrequencyC { get; set; }
    int? JapaneseForBusyPeople { get; set; }
    int? AJlpt { get; set; }
    int? TJlpt { get; set; }
    bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Your `PhraseAndScore` class implements it:

```
public class PhraseAndScore : IPhrase
{
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Romaji { get; set; }
    public string Kana { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    public int OneHash { get; set; }
    public int TwoHash { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyA { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyB { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyC { get; set; }
    public int? JapaneseForBusyPeople { get; set; }
    public int? AJlpt { get; set; }
    public int? TJlpt { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int EnglishCorrect { get; set; }
    public int KanaCorrect { get; set; }
    public int RomajiCorrect { get; set; }
    public int KanjiCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Phrase` class implements it the interface too:

```
public class Phrase : IPhrase
{
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Romaji { get; set; }
    public string Kana { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    public int OneHash { get; set; }
    public int TwoHash { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyA { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyB { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyC { get; set; }
    public int? JapaneseForBusyPeople { get; set; }
    public int? AJlpt { get; set; }
    public int? TJlpt { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then instantiate the list:

```
List<IPhrase> all = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>().Where(filter).ToList();
```

## EDIT

Oh, my bad. `List<T>` requires the `T` argument to be invariantly valid.  You need a set that allows for covariant `T`. So you need to use `IEnumerable<out T>`. [More info on covariance.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

```
IEnumerable<IPhrase> all = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>().Where(filter).ToList(); // or ToArray() or whatever implementation of IEnumerable<out IPhrase>
```

Or, inside a method just use implicit typing:

```
var all = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>().Where(filter).ToList(); // or ToArray() or whatever implementation of IEnumerable<out IPhrase>
```

Comment: I like the idea of the interface but when I tried it then I still get the same cannot convert message. Could this because I am using List<> ?

Comment: Also tried using select like you suggested but that gave me a problem.  I added what I tried to the question.

Comment: var all = db2.Query<PhraseAndScore>(select + filter);

                List<IPhrase> abc = all.Where(x => x.EnglishCorrect > 0);

Answer (score 1):

Without reflection or automapper, no, there is not.

Consider designing your domain model better, e.g. using composition:

```
public class Phrase
{
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Romaji { get; set; }
    public string Kana { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    public int OneHash { get; set; }
    public int TwoHash { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyA { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyB { get; set; }
    public int? FrequencyC { get; set; }
    public int? JapaneseForBusyPeople { get; set; }
    public int? AJlpt { get; set; }
    public int? TJlpt { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class Score
{
    public int EnglishCorrect { get; set; }
    public int KanaCorrect { get; set; }
    public int RomajiCorrect { get; set; }
    public int KanjiCorrect { get; set; }
}

public class ScoredPhrase
{
    public Phrase Phrase { get; set; }
    public Score Score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this won't help as I do a SQL select into List<ScoredPhrase>

Comment: and what about complex type? https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) ?
It is useful to convert and load similar objects to each other.

Comment: Might be too much for this as I just have this one need